# How to recognize structures in dates with python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and in the column `just_dates` there are the dates where the user was active, for example:

```
      just_dates                Count
0    2015-06-01                   89
1    2015-06-02                   44
2    2015-06-03                   61
3    2015-06-04                   47
4    2015-06-05                   82
5    2015-06-09                   46
12   2015-06-19                   42
13   2015-06-21                    1
14   2015-06-22                   68
15   2015-06-23                   82
..          ...                  ...
529  2017-05-24                   86
535  2017-06-02                   63
536  2017-06-04                    1
537  2017-06-05                   28
538  2017-06-06                   77
```

Is there a way where I can check if the user was at least two time a week online? In this case the user waste least two time active in the first week, than not just the same like in the penultimate and in the last week he was?
I also like to add an tolerance where he need not to be active two times a week at a certain time.

Comment: How can you identify if a user has logged in at least two times over the past week, if you don't have a user ID in your data?

Comment: This is just a extract of the data. It's always the same user. So, this is a protocol of an unique user

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick, assuming that dataframe `df` contains information for a single user:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-06-01', 1], ['2015-06-02', 3], ['2016-06-23', 1]], columns=['just_dates', 'Count'])

# Convert just_dates to datetime
df['just_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['just_dates'])
weekly_counts = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='just_dates', freq='W')).Count.sum()

print(weekly_counts.where(weekly_counts > 1).dropna())
```

And the output should be:

```
just_dates
2015-06-07    4.0
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Count, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do you use the column 'Count' from my extract? Because I just want to use the column 'just_dates'..

Comment: @Dennis So you don't want to use the column `Count`?

Comment: @Dennis I think you are missing something. What if a user has visited the page only once on the first and second day of a week? How would you able to identify that he visited the page at least twice in that week, without taking into account the counts?

Comment: I want to know if the user visited the page on 2 day the week. So, he has to visit the page at 2 different days in the week